# When to use execute @form and @this in Jsf Ajax requests on Command buttons

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to understand the behavior of `execute="@form"` and `execute="@this"`.

I am using Jsf 2.2 version.

```
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="{agreement.save}" >
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

I am trying to understand the behavior of the following things.

1. When to use `execute="@form"` and `execute="@this"` on command button.
2. What is significance of `render="@form"`.
3. Is it suggested to use @form in ajax requests.

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25339056/1391249). It is about PrimeFaces where `process` and `update` correspond to `execute` and `render` respectively.

Comment: @tiny: why not create this as an answer before a 'half baked' one is posted?

Comment: It is already answered there in great detail.